# { Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax

Tags: mysql, syntax

> { Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check
>   the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'undefined' at line 1

I've tried adding back ticks in the table columns but that didn't work.

```
function quantityCheck(ID, itemsPurchased){
    connection.query('Select * FROM `products` WHERE `item_id` ' + ID, function(err, res){
        if (err){console.log(err)};
        if(itemsPurchased <= res[0].stock_quantity){
            var total = res[0].price * itemsPurchased;
            console.log('Your items are available for final purchase.')
            console.log ('Total today for ' + itemsPurchased + ' ' + res[0].product_name + ' is ' + total);

            connection.query('UPDATE products SET stock_quantity = stock_quantity -' + itemsPurchased + 'WHERE item_id = ' + ID);
        } else {
            console.log ('Your purchase could not be processed. We have limited quantities of ' + res[0].product_name);
        }
        display();
    })
```

I'm wanting to show the quantityCheck(); code after the connection.query method.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a whitespace in your SQL

Change

```
connection.query('UPDATE products SET stock_quantity = stock_quantity -' + itemsPurchased + 'WHERE item_id = ' + ID);
```

To

```
connection.query('UPDATE products SET stock_quantity = stock_quantity -' + itemsPurchased + ' WHERE item_id = ' + ID);
```

Notice i've inserted an extra whitespace before WHERE

Also, consider using prepared statements instead to avoid SQL injection attacks

Answer (score 0):

It's mostly due to proper spacing in your `update` statement. Should be like below. Again your query currently vulnerable to *Sql Injection* attack. Use a parameterized query instead

```
connection.query('UPDATE products SET stock_quantity = stock_quantity - ' + itemsPurchased + ' WHERE item_id = ' + ID);
```